MySQL Password Not Working using Homebrew
I've been using homebrew to start and stop MySQL, but, it randomly stopped working, and keeps giving the acess Denied for User 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES).
I'm 100% sure the password is right, and sudo mysql -uroot -p and other variants haven't been working. Also I can't access MySQL mode in the ternimal without doing MySQL -u root -p,which causes the issue. The linked so-called duplicate does not work in this situation. Also will it work just to uninstall MySQL using Homebrew and then re install it the regular way. , I have torn my hair out over this. Also I am using mac. Thanks!
